# how to upload SWF format in php?

Tags: php

My source code is to print upload SWF file tmp_name ?

```
<?php
echo json_encode($_FILES);
?>
 <form method="POST" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
      <input type="file" id="image" name="image" />
       <input id="send" type="submit" name="data" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

But result i'm  getting

```
{"image":{"name":"file.swf","type":"","tmp_name":"","error":1,"size":0}}
```

I have tried image uploading method no use on that !

Comment: Have you checked what is error `1` stands for?

Answer (score 0):

```
{"image":{"name":"file.swf","type":"","tmp_name":"","error":1,"size":0}} 
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^
```

This error isn't specific to Flash at all. You'd run into the same issue with other formats as well.

[Error 1 is `UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE`](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php). It means that the file you tried to upload was larger than your server's maximum upload size ([`upload_max_filesize`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize)), so the server didn't accept it.

Change this configuration value, or upload a smaller file.